# How to add tags to Consul watch

Tags: watch, consul

I'm a bit confused. I have such a file for the Consul (v.1.0.7) watch.

```
{
  "watches": [{
      "type": "service",
      "service": "server-devenv-devplatform-common",
            "tag": ["devenv","devplatform","common"],
            "args": ["/opt/consul_watches_handler.sh"]
    }]
}
```

It doesn't work as expected giving me this error:

```
Failed reloading watches: Failed to parse watch (map[string]interface {}{\"tag\":[]interface {}{\"devenv\", \"devplatform\", \"common\"}, \"args\":[]interface {}{\"/opt/consul_watches_handler.sh\"}}): Expecting tag to be a string)"] "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Without a line with a **tag**, it works fine. But It's made as described in the manual:

https://www.consul.io/docs/dynamic-app-config/watches

and also works at other servers with a tag.
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use multiple tags in a service watch handler was added in Consul 1.5.0 with PR [hashicorp/consul#5725](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/pull/5725).

This version requirement is not called out in the docs, nor was the feature addition listed in the [Consul 1.5.0 changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150-may-08-2019) so it is completely understandable that you are not aware of this minimum version requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Blake Covarrubias. You helped very much. I'm new with Consul so I didn't know about these updates. The reason for the old version is that while provisioning it was commented in code some playbooks responsible for the Consul update. Anyway, the Consul update fixed the issue. Thank you!